# How to write regular expression for decimal ifor wcf ria service meta data?

Tags: c#, regex, wcf-ria-services

Suppose I have decimal property for an entity meta data for wcf ria service:

```
 public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }
```

I want to the input for this field is something like 0.00, means user must input 2 digitals after decimal dot. If there is nothing, .00 must be there.  So, 123.00, 12.23 is file. But 12 or 3345 is not right.

Then I want to put regular expression as validation attribute on this property in meta data class. 
How can I do it?
Any other solution?

Thanks for answer, guys. Here is the testing:

```
 [RegularExpression("^\\d*\\.\\d{2}$", ErrorMessage = "Put the right number for amount")]
 public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }
```

This is not working. all 123, 123., 123.00 are acceptable.

Above solution only working for string, like this:

```
 [RegularExpression("^\\d*\\.\\d{2}$", ErrorMessage = "Put the right number for amount")]
 public string Amount { get; set; }
```

How to make it working for Decimal?

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

`\d*\.\d\d`

Comment: Thanks. After put it for the property, 123 did not raise any exception. Maybe above expression only working for string, not decimal type?

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression

```
^\d*\.\d{2}$
```

`^` is the anchor for start of the string

`\d` is a digit

`*` means zero or more of the preceding expression, here `\d`

`{2}` says exactly 2 of the preceding expression, here `\d`

`$` is the anchor for the end of the string

If you don't use the anchors, you can put anything what you want in front or behind and it will match.